# Analytic query trying to solve

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i`m solving the following task with analytic functions and i`m stuck.

task: Write a query that shows the latest hired employee per department. In case of ties, use the lowest employee ID.

```
select  a.EMPLOYEE_ID,
        a.DEPARTMENT_ID,
        a.FIRST_NAME,
        a.LAST_NAME,
        a.HIRE_DATE,
        a.JOB_ID
from (select ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by department_id order by hire_date desc)    
from hr.EMPLOYEES a) A
where A = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the columns you want to select in the outer query in the `SELECT` clause of the inner query and need to give an alias to the `ROW_NUMBER` computed value:

```sql
select  EMPLOYEE_ID,
        DEPARTMENT_ID,
        FIRST_NAME,
        LAST_NAME,
        HIRE_DATE,
        JOB_ID
from (
  select EMPLOYEE_ID,
         DEPARTMENT_ID,
         FIRST_NAME,
         LAST_NAME,
         HIRE_DATE,
         JOB_ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by department_id order by hire_date desc) AS rn
  from   hr.EMPLOYEES
)
where  rn = 1 ;
```

You still need to address the second part of the question:

> In case of ties, use the lowest employee ID.

However, since this appears to be a homework question, I'll leave that for you to solve.

Comment: any hints that can help me find the answer :(

Comment: @Jony_Junior I gave you the answer to your syntax problems; you just need to amend the `ORDER BY` clause to solve the last part if two employees are tied on the same latest `hire_date`.

Comment: ohhhh it was so obvious. I don`t know how i didn`t taught  about it ... thank you man !